# Bootstrap css not getting applied to the custom Wordpress Dashboard Widget

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I am facing difficulty applying Bootstrap to my custom dashboard widget.

```
function admin_theme_style() {
    if( is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-script', plugin_dir_url($this->_FILE_) . 'includes/js/bootstrap.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core', false, array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('google-platform', '//apis.google.com/js/platform.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_style('webinar', plugin_dir_url($this->_FILE_) . 'includes/css/webinar.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', plugin_dir_url($this->_FILE_) . 'includes/css/bootstrap.css');    
    }

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'admin_theme_style');
```

For the plugin, scripts and CSS gets loaded correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure of your `$this->_FILE_` syntax. Also, I'm not sure Bootstrap's JavaScript should be enqueued before it's CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the add_action() should be

```
add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, 
            int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

You've got the tag and then you have an array. That array should just be a string of 'admin_theme_style'. That should call the entire function.

[add_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)

Simply try:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_theme_style');
```

Comment: As you could guess, the OP's code belongs to a class. So, you are wrong.